# SBS 2011 Standard: Task Manager & regedit disabled

Tags: windows, task-manager, regedit, windows-sbs

I have now this very strange issue:

Suddenly I cannot start `taskmgr.exe` and `regedit.exe`.
I get the error message that it has been disabled by the Administrator but I am working with the Administrator account and I disabled it [Apart from that I don't even know how to do it without Google].

As you can see the Task-Manager is disabled

[image]

This is the error messages I receive when I start these programs by entering their program names [it is in German but it is clear what it means]:

[image]

The setting in the group policy `gpedit.msc` for Task Manager is this [but I think it is for the clients which are working on the domain and does not apply for the SBS it self]:

[image]

I don't really remember what I should have done wrong:

1. I was cleaning up the User folder [only the temp directories].
2. I was restarting the Exchange Information Store service because I changed the maximal RAM from 12 to 10 GB.
3. I installed the Patch [cleaner](http://www.homedev.com.au/free/patchcleaner) but this cannot be a malware. I ran it on several other Servers without any problem!

Few minutes before it worked and suddenly it stopped.

Any idea how I messed up the SBS?

Comment: This doesn't just happen. This is an old school malware trick. You can use the `reg query` command from command prompt and check `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\Current Version\Policies\System` for the malicious policy. You can run `REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System  /v  DisableTaskMgr  /t REG_DWORD  /d /0 /f` to enable task manager. Your system is probably crawling with malware though.

Comment: You'll have to do it in "offline" mode then. You can boot a live Windows CD/USB drive and mount the registry and make the changes. This is the least of your problems though if your server is infected.

Comment: Both "User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> CTRL+ALT+DEL options" and "Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> CTRL+ALT+DEL options".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible a Group Policy may have inadvertently disabled Task Manager and the Registry Editor by accident. It is also very possible that the machine you are using is infected. You should scan it for malware. To solve your immediate problem, you can do one of a few things:

1. Try using [UnHookExec.inf](http://securityresponse.symantec.com/avcenter/UnHookExec.inf) from Symantec. Right-click and save this file to a folder, and then right-click and click "Install". This should re-enable the Registry Editor.
2. From there, you can [re-enable Task Manager](https://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/103275-task-manager-enable-disable.html) using the [provided REG file](https://www.vistax64.com/attachments/tutorials/22386d1297044709-task-manager-enable-disable-enable_task_manager-reg) or via the registry manually.

Comment: I ran already a malware scan and there was a malware. It removed the registry settings and now all works fine! +1